# why is rspec running different numbers of tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I realize this is a very broad question but I've seen our tests run 800 or 1,500 individual tests and pass both times. What could be causing `rspec` to run a different number of tests on different builds?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is do with Rspec running test in random order. See here for more information.

[Rspec order option](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/order)

for example if you want to see the same test results and still want to run them randomly you can do following

> When you use --order random, RSpec prints out the random number it
>   used to seed the randomizer.
>
> --order rand:1234 --order default tells RSpec to load groups and examples as they are declared in each file

```
bundle exec rspec --order rand ## for example this will results with a seed 1234
```

if you want to run same number of test in same random order you can run

```
bundle exec spec --order rand:1234 # This will always run the test in same random order with the given seed (1234)
```

Comment: Thanks! You are correct that using the same seed does let me recreate the number of specs that were run. But, I can't find any clue as to why all of the specs aren't running.

Comment: hmm only thing I can think of based on provided details is may be it is something to with pattern , https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/pattern-option

Comment: Mostly likely is that the last test run by any seed is silently bombing the suite?

Comment: @TomDunning had it exactly right. The last test in every run was the problem. I have no idea why but taking it out of the rotation fixed the problem.